# how to get a report in jenkins from maven pom.xml for dependency check

Tags: maven, security, jenkins, owasp

I modified the pom.xml by adding dependency-check plugin. I add also the plugin in jenkins , should I add a stage in Jenkins file ? 
Jenkins file:

```
 stage('Dependency Check') {
                dependencyCheckAnalyzer datadir: 'dependency-check-data', isFailOnErrorDisabled: true, hintsFile: '',
                    includeCsvReports: false, includeHtmlReports: false, includeJsonReports: false,
                    isAutoupdateDisabled: false, outdir: '', scanpath: '', skipOnScmChange: false,
                    skipOnUpstreamChange: false, suppressionFile: '', zipExtensions: ''
                dependencyCheckPublisher canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', healthy: '', pattern: '', unHealthy: ''
                archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '**/dependency-check-report.xml', onlyIfSuccessful: true
            }
```

pom.xml :

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

please any help 
thank you